# 3 Headed Display Ubuntu Wallpaper

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-10.04, gnome

I got 3 display working in Linux.  I have set it up so I have Xinerama and 3 different X sessions.  So my 3 displays are not all the same size, two are 1680x1050 and then the other which is between the two is 2560x1600. So my issue is when I chose span, even if the image is larger than all 3 resolutions combined, the center monitor has bars at the top and the bottom because span scales the image it seems.  Is there a way if I bypass the gui to have an image span all three monitors but with no scaling?

Urgent! Please help! ;-)

Comment: Urgent. I just lol'd. =D (Note: Be happy if it works at least. Don't try to mess with it. :))

Comment: @Shiki: Ya, took me a while to get to the point of working, now I want the final touch :-)  (Nice Gendo avatar)

Comment: Well.. try a tiling WM if you want to experience some more pain and useless spending of time. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with one option after a flashback to the 90s...

From Terminal:

```
gconf-editor
```

The in Apps/Nautilus/Preferences uncheck "Show Desktop"

Then in the gconf editor:

```
display -window root ~/Pictures/KeswickCropped.bmp
```